# NextJs next-router-worker consuming more memory space. M1 MacBook gets lock automatically due to heavy memory usage

Tags: next.js13

Recently I was working on a NextJs project and my mac suddenly gets blank, it get locked. After some findings I checked the processes on activity monitor, there I found one process which was consuming 1.9GB of memory space which made the mac to lock the screen.

My project has some routes in that ( like home, library, about ) so that I created a new NextJs project and ran that preloaded template and checked the activity monitor once again and what there was same **next-router-worker** which has taken a quit big memory space ( 2.02GB ).

Why is this happening or have I made some errors ?

If anybody knows Please help, this is what  [next-router-worker process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9lCI.png) looks like

NextJs version - v13
device - M1 Macbook

Answer (score 4):

I have also noticed the memory leak issue with the `next-worker-router`. In my case, it spiked around upto 2-3 GB before running out of RAM. There has been a fix to this issue with version `13.4.13-canary.12`.

It was caused by exits not cleaning up properly by `router-server`

I suggest you to upgrade to the latest Next version 14 or if you're too strict on making the change, to upgrade to `v13.4.13-canary.12` or above.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you got this from? Upgrading didn't help for me

Comment: This issue which is closed points out that it fixes the issue. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53571. After upgrading, I couldn't find next-worker-router in the background processes anymore instead I saw router-server. I guess you could lookup and see if this process is using a higher memory. In my case, it was relatively low and stayed below 700MB during the development workflow.